# How to disable background dimming during OpenContainer animation?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-animation

I'm using the animation package (OpenContainer) to open a new search page in my app, as shown in the example on the package's website: https://pub.dev/packages/animations#container-transform.

A user taps on a search bar and a new page expands, slowly filling the space from top to bottom. The problem is, I don't like the background dimming effect - the screen behind becomes darker during the animation phase. Is there a way to disable or overwrite it?